# Updating Realm Object in Swift from in Different thread/session

Tags: ios, swift, realm

After saving the realm objects i doing the following

```
 try! self.realm.write{
       article.imageUri = path
       try! self.realm.commitWrite()
 }
```

although I can see the value while i am still in the same session of the simulator, after restarting or rerunning the app the update value in the snippet above doesn't show, but the rest of the data is there

this update is done after fetching data using Alamofire result

Answer (score 3):

First thing, when you call write with a block, you don't need to specify `try! self.realm.commitWrite()` inside the block.  That's automatically called for you as per Realm's example:

```
try! realm.write {
  realm.add(myDog)
}
```

You only need to call `self.realm.commitWrite()` when you have previously called `self.realm.beginWrite()`

Secondly, It's hard to say exactly why you might not be seeing the data update with more context.  What's article?  Where's that being set?  How is the Realm being loaded/stored?  Are you deleting the Simulator app in between runs?  There's a lot of variables here.

Comment: i have done it with the commit, and because i was facing this issue i did it,

Comment: i have done it with the commit, and because i was facing this issue i did it, article is a ream object, data bing set inside a Alamofire result block which uses NSSessions, and as stated before when the data are being loaded after update it works fine, only after i close the simulator, restart, or rerun the app i don't seem to get it. thank for your help